# How to reduce verbosity of googletest (overwrite two methods of the default listener)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I would like to suppress overly verbose "RUN" and "OK" output lines from googletest, while maintaining all other output from the default listener.

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#defining-event-listeners describes:

(1) how to replace the default listener by a custom listener, or

(2) how to add an additional listener.

Unfortunately, this does not exactly solve my problem. Modification (1) would also suppress other messages, unless I reimplement them. Modification (2) does not overwrite the default methods, but only adds additional output.

For the wanted solution, my listener would inherit from the default listener, and not from `EmptyTestEventListener`.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default listener is called `PrettyUnitTestResultPrinter`. It is implemented in `src/gtest.cc`. Unfortunately, it is not *declared* in a `.h` file. Therefore there is no straightforward way to inherit from it.

Therefore the easiest solution to my problem is a brutal one: Copy all of googletest to a `ThirdParty/gtest` directory in my project, and **patch** `src/gtest.cc`. Just search for "RUN" and "OK" and delete the unwanted output commands.

Comment: Reported as a feature request at https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/771.